# Two sonic booms colliding

Tags: acoustics, collision, interference, shock-waves

If I theoretically created an experiment where I could create two sonic booms in directions such that the sonic "nose" is facing each other; what would happen?

more specifically:

Lets suppose I have a sonic boom A in the opposite direction of a sonic boom B in the opposite direction of A (facing each other).

A--><--B

if I could theoretically keep the objects creating each boom from colliding and allowed the boom nose to get infinitesimally close together, and each object could stop instantly after "booming", what would occur near the nose of the collision? Given that the pressure is controlled and the velocity is *mach 1* respectively.

Comment: ultimately they are waves, and not physical, so as far as i understand, the waves will pass through eachother

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but the sheer amount of energy  that accumulated would affect the propagation of the wave. I do believe they will pass through in the aftermath, but what happens at that instant of "collision"?

Comment: Shock waves do not pass through each other like solitons, they would constructively and destructively interfere, depending on the geometry and conditions.  The problem is that if one piston/driver were to pass into the downstream of the shock created by the other, chances are it would suddenly enter a medium where it is no longer supersonic.  That is, the compressed/shocked gas has higher sound speeds than the ambient media so it requires higher speed pistons to generate shock waves.

Answer (score -2):

I think they will collide and create a standing wave, high pressure, have you seen acoustic levitation? it's the same, but a lot less energy...

Comment: Do you have any justification for your opinions? Or any sort of logic at all that would support them?

Comment: well... 2 waves that collide create a standing wave. that is a fact. School science class... basics of waves. and in this precise case, please go to youtube and search acoustic levitation, its there, scientists are levitating objects between 2 sound waves that collide each other, create standing waves which create high pressures zones and low pressure zones.

Comment: Standing waves are created _in a cavity_ by waves _of only certain frequencies_ which depend on the geometry of the cavity. Nowhere was a cavity mentioned in the setup. It's just two sonic booms colliding in open air.

Comment: Maybe you are right. Maybe standing wave is not right word here .